# Log output shows in Jenkins while running bash script to execute Java code

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, jenkins

At first let me describe my issue.
I configured Jenkins and after build action I called shell script to run bash script on remote server.
The shell script starts application via command

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=xxx 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -jar name.jar "BUILD_PARAMETER"
```

I see logs from my application in Jenkins build, and it's keep build process running. I need to finish it after running 
sh run command. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you trying to start shell script on another server from Jenkins server? what is your command?

Comment: @Naggi Yes, exactly, on different server. I have tried ***nohup sh run.sh*** and ***sh run.sh***.

Comment: You are missing the `&` at the end of the command. That's what sends the process to the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this using Jenkins you will need to use the nohup notation as in the comments as well as specifying a non-numerial PID for the process. Jenkins tries to clean up after a job finishes by killing any processes it starts.

BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup <-your command -> &

the above command should work

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build

Answer (score 1):

Your shell script need to fork a process, and return, otherwise Jenkins thinks your shell script is still running (which it is, if it's not forking the process and returning).

You have not provided the command you use to launch your application, but a common way to fork a process in linux is:

`nohup <your command here> &`

Comment: My command to launch application is content of run.sh script and it's in main post.

Comment: So use `nohup java <your arguments> &` inside your `run.sh` file.

Comment: I had <code>nohup sh run.sh &</code> at Jenkins but didn't think about changing run.sh :). I'll try this one.

Comment: Jenkins still receives logs. I updated OP. My command in run.sh script has parameter, currently I don't pass any value there.  Couild it affect & key?